# c# Using [jsonproperty] for key when posting

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have an external webservice that i try to post some values to. I found out that im not using the right model to post the data. The thing is that the webservice expects square brackets in their property names.

So my model looks like this:

```
public class person
{
        [JsonProperty("person[name]")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("person[misc]")]
        public string Misc { get; set; }
}
```

When posting its using the Name as key but i'd like the JsonProperty value to be used because thats what the webservice accepts. Is there a way to use the JsonProperty or do i have to manually add the remaining parts?

Comment: So what does the generated JSON actually look like, and what does it expect it to look like? I'd expect that to be okay, assuming you're using the right serializer...

Comment: I just found out my JSON is empty and it returns a empty array when its trying to do the following: var attrs = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonProperty), true); I would assume it would return the JsonProperty described in my class?

Comment: Well you should be checking for `JsonPropertyAttribute` to start with...